# non-singular matrix. Show if $a^TAa \neq -1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ a nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix and $a$ $\in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Show that if $a^TAa \neq -1$, then

$(A+aa^T)^{-1}= A^{-1} -\frac{1}{1+a^TAa}A^{-1}aa^TA^{-1}$

I just don't see how I can apply any invertible matrixes properties here.  What approach should I take?

Comment: What if $a^TAa=-1$?

Comment: If I want to show $X^{-1}$ is $Y$, I try multiplying out $XY$ and $YX$ to see if I get the identity.  Actually, I only need to compute one of $XY$ or $YX$, because with matrices, a left inverse is always a right inverse.

Comment: @JCAA I changed my comment before you posted yours to incorporate what you said.  You are correct that there must be some mistake in the OPs question.

Comment: sorry I mistyped it. I have corrected it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Try multiplying out $$(A+aa^T)\left(A^{-1} -\frac{1}{1+a^TAa}A^{-1}aa^TA^{-1}\right)$$ and see what you get. Note that you may have to appropriately group terms to simplify this to get the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Try using the following the Woodbury matrix identity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity.

\begin{align}
(A+UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1}-A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).

Check the statement and the proof in the linked Wikipedia article.